# Calling constructor at the same time dynamic array is defined - Java

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

**Using this example:**

```
public class ExampleData {

  private List<String> directories;
  private String exampleString;


  public ExampleData (String[] directories, String exampleString) {
    this.directories = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.<String> asList(directories));
    this.exampleString= exampleString;
  }
}
```

**Calling the constructor:**

```
public class Test{

  private String[] directories={"/tmp/17","/tmp/18"};
  private ExampleData eD = 
        new ExampleData(directories, "Test");
}
```

**Why can I call its constructor with the previous code and not with the next one:**

```
public class Test{

  private ExampleData eD = 
        new ExampleData({"/tmp/17","/tmp/18"}, "Test");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java just doesn't accept that syntax. You can instead write

```
private ExampleData eD = 
    new ExampleData(new String[]{"/tmp/17", "/tmp/18"}, "Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

because, you need to first create /tmp/17 and /tmp/18 than you can put them in a list or whatever.  Their constructor need to be called seperatly.

moreover, idk what language you are coding with but ({"/tmp/17","/tmp/18"},.....) this seems wrong. I mean curvey braces in braces...